# Jsoup trouble to select menuitem

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```html
<span style="display:none"><menu type='ServerMenu' id="EE18_ViewSelectorMenu" CompactMode="true"><ie:menuitem id="EE19_DefaultView" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/1A.aspx';" text="1A" menuGroupId="100"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE20_View1" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/1ACPGEATS.aspx';" text="1A.CPGE-ATS" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE21_View2" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/1ADUTGE.aspx';" text="1A.DUT-GE" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE22_View3" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/1ADUTGI.aspx';" text="1A.DUT-GI" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE23_View4" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/2A.aspx';" text="2A" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE24_View5" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/2AVaASR.aspx';" text="2A.Va.ASR" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE25_View6" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/2AVaMSE.aspx';" text="2A.Va.MSE" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE26_View7" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/2AVaTSI.aspx';" text="2A.Va.TSI" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE27_View8" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3A.aspx';" text="3A" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE28_View9" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3ADADc_Cloud.aspx';" text="3A.DA.Dc_Cloud" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE29_View10" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3ADAScurit.aspx';" text="3A.DA.S&#233;curit&#233;" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE30_View11" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3ADASI_Cloud.aspx';" text="3A.DA.SI_Cloud" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE31_View12" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3ADASI_Sante.aspx';" text="3A.DA.SI_Sant&#233;" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE32_View13" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/3ADATransport.aspx';" text="3A.DA.Transport" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE33_View14" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/calendar.aspx';" text="Calendrier" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE34_View15" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/MyItems.aspx';" text="&#201;v&#233;nements actuels" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE35_View16" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/Export.aspx';" text="Export" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE36_View17" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/RssView1.aspx';" text="RssView" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE37_View18" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/Salles.aspx';" text="Salles" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE38_View19" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/AllItems.aspx';" text="Tous les &#233;v&#233;nements" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE39_View20" type="option" onMenuClick="window.location = '/Lists/Promo 2015/Video.aspx';" text="Video" menuGroupId="300"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="EE40_CreateView" type="option" iconSrc="/_layouts/images/createview.gif" onMenuClick="window.location = '/_layouts/ViewType.aspx?';" text="Cr&#233;er un affichage" menuGroupId="400"></ie:menuitem></menu></span>
```

How can I get all the information  begin with "onMenuClick="window.location " ?

I'm using this code "Elements links3 = doc.select("menu[id=zz18_ViewSelectorMenu]");" to get into menu but i can't get into menuitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jsoup library for android[JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)

```
try {
            if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
                ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
            }
            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .parse("<span style=\"display:none\"><menu type='ServerMenu' id=\"zz18_ViewSelectorMenu\" CompactMode=\"true\"><ie:menuitem id=\"zz19_DefaultView\" type=\"option\" onMenuClick=\"window.location = '/etudes/Portal/edt/Lists/Promo 2015/1A.aspx';\" text=\"1A\" menuGroupId=\"100\"></ie:menuitem>");
            String requiredaspxpage = doc.select("menu#zz18_ViewSelectorMenu")
                    .get(0).children().get(0).attr("onMenuClick");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Elements links3 = doc.select("menu#zz18_ViewSelectorMenu");
     for (Element link : links3) {
       System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.children().get(22).attr("onMenuClick"));
     } Give me outofboundsException Invalid index 22, size is 22, can you solve it ?

Comment: size 22 if you want last elemnt use get(21)

Comment: i answered  on your other question

Comment: Ok i just edited my question can you answer it again pls

Comment: i am talking about other question

Comment: i just edited and added a partial htlm code witch contain 34 onMenueclick, i want to select all of them i can't give the full code sorry it's secure with password

Comment: it has just 22 childs

Comment: check the other question answer it has only 22 elemnts